# Android Looper quits but keeps open files/pipes

Tags: android, android-build, android-framework, android-memory

I noticed that whenever a thread that runs with a `Looper` object is finished (i.e. `Looper.quit()` is called), some files remain open (3 files usually).
You can see that by running "**adb shell ls /proc//fd | wc -l**"
This happens because the `MessageQueue` inside `Looper` is never freed, although it's never used.
Only if I call the `finalize()` method on the `MessageQueue`, then these files are freed.
The files may remain open hours after the thread is finished.
This causes a problem when these threads run in system process because there are many open files already, and I can't exceed the 1024 file boundary.
(BTW even when I call `System.gc()` it doesn't finalize `MessageQueue`)

Is there anyway (without using reflection) to have `MessageQueue` finalize method invoked?
It seems to me like a bug in Android that the GC doesn't do it by itself even when the number of open files is big.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should post a bug report http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NitroG42 as it turns out someone beat me to it and posted this bug almost a year ago.
It is currently assigned to JBQ.
You can find the bug report here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41645&q=messagequeue&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&